# How can I add coreIdentity to existing DB

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I have problem with adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore to my project. I have created db already (code-first) and now i need to add some tables, that are necessary to create login and register system.

i've tried to do some tutorials how to do it, but i have always the same error. Probably i forgot about smth easy.

I have 2 controllers, Home and Account. Home is doing operations on products and products lists. Account have to let me register users and let them login.

```cs
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
                                  SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {


            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Main_menu", "Home");
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }

            }

            return View();
        }
    }
```

and my Context(I'm creating there 3 table, but db have much more becouse of IdentityDbContext)

```cs
 public class ProductContext : IdentityDbContext
    {

        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }

        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<ProductList> ProductLists { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=database.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductList>()
                .HasKey(pl => new { pl.ProductId, pl.ListId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductList>()
                .HasOne(pl => pl.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProductList)
                .HasForeignKey(pl => pl.ProductId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductList>()
                .HasOne(pl => pl.List)
                .WithMany(l => l.ProductList)
                .HasForeignKey(pl => pl.ListId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
```

and my View:

```cs
@model RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1>Rejestracja</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                Haslo:
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Powtorz Haslo:
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zarejestruj</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And startup:

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            var contentRoot = configuration.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey);
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProductContext>();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {

                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

When i want to move to this view i have:

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'PracaInz.Models.ProductContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,PracaInz.Models.ProductContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.

Is it possible to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore to code-first database?

In whole project i have more views and i can move between it. The error appears only when im trying to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.
The error concerns Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore.
The tables are empty.

When i dont have HttpPost Register method, i can move to the view. The problem is when im adding HttpPost method.

Comment: Have you tried creating the relationship between `IdentityUser` and another table? As far as I can remember it should work after that. Just try it out. Remember to update the database after changing the entities.

Comment: I don't need to link user with lists. I just need login and register system. IdentityTables are ready to use, its created in DB.

Comment: And which line of code are you encountering the exception?

Comment: im not catching it, i mean the error is when im trying to go to view with register

Comment: im getting the exception when clicking on button wchich should call the Register function

Comment: Did you run the Add-Migration and Update-Database commands?

Comment: yes, before it i didnt have any aspnetroles(tables in db) etc. now i have, so update works.

Comment: Show the AddDbContext line from Startup class.

Comment: `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProductContext>();`

Comment: to call db im using: ```c# using (var db = new ProductContext())
            {
                some code
            }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to add

```cs
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and delete

```cs
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProductContext>();
```

in startup.
the error was about bad startup configuration.
Was sending too much things.

ApplicationDbContext:

```cs
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }

        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<ProductList> ProductLists { get; set; }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

             optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=assistant.db");

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductList>()
                .HasKey(pl => new { pl.ProductId, pl.ListId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductList>()
                .HasOne(pl => pl.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProductList)
                .HasForeignKey(pl => pl.ProductId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductList>()
                .HasOne(pl => pl.List)
                .WithMany(l => l.ProductList)
                .HasForeignKey(pl => pl.ListId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
```